# Auto scroll happening with ScrollView and not getting margin bottom through RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show 10 green boxes in a `LinearLayout` and I'm facing two issues. I have defined the margin-bottom through `params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100)`, but it is not working. Another problem is that I'm inserting the 10 green boxes through `MainActivity.java` using the `.addView()`, and when they have been inserted the `ScrollView` shows the scroll being at the bottom. So when the app opens, the 10th green box is shows on the screen where I want the 1st green box to appear, so how can I turn off this auto-scroll.

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java:`

```
package com.example.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout content = findViewById(R.id.content);

        for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {
            RelativeLayout element = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100); // NOT GETTING THE MARGIN BOTTOM
            element.setLayoutParams(params);
            element.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
            content.addView(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "but it is not working" mean?

Comment: The margin-bottom is not being made

Comment: @JustinJasmann Or is it being made for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined your views to be added on 'content' i.e. LinearLayout so create LayoutParams to be Linear as well that would solve it. Rest are same.

Here is my changes for you:(in your java class)

```
LinearLayout content = findViewById(R.id.content);
for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {
        RelativeLayout element = new RelativeLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100); // now should work
        element.setLayoutParams(params);
        element.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        content.addView(element);
    }
```

xml file need not be changed

plus when i opened the app the scroll view is at top as it should be.